# How can I detect whether my code is running "inside" Sidekiq server or Puma?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, connection-pooling, sidekiq, puma

I'm using Puma as a web server, and Sidekiq as my queue runner.

For multiple things (Database connections, Redis connections, other external services) I'm using the ConnectionPool gem to manage safe access to connections.

Now, depending on whether I'm running in the context of Sidekiq or of Puma, I need those pools to be different sizes (as large as the number of Sidekiq Threads or Puma threads respectively, and they are different)

What is the best way to know, in your initializers, how big to make your connection pools based on execution context?

Thanks!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You use [`Sidekiq.server?`](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/528ca61ab270198fe56f65bbf35265790e3ae748/lib/sidekiq.rb#L87) which returns `nil` when not running inside the Sidekiq process itself.

Comment: Except for sidekiq enterprise. On sidekiq enterprise I now get a string back which contains "constant". Which was not the case before upgrading to enterprise. Happened on trinidad...

Comment: You should open an issue because that is incorrect.

Comment: @user934801 You probably `require sidekiq/cli` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your specific case (`puma`/`sidekiq`), but in general you can find this information in the `$PROGRAM_NAME` variable. Also similar are `$0` and `__FILE__`.